# Jquery display value of input type file to other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display the value/name of an input file to an element. The code runs normal .. but the problem is when the user clicks and select a file . the file doesn't show up the **moment** the user selects the file but instead it shows when user clicks on the upload button again . so how will i make the value of the input field to show up the moment the user makes the choice .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filename").each(function () {
        $('.upload').click(function () {
            $('#file_button').click();
            var file = $('#file_button').val();
            if (file !== null) {
                if ($('.filename').val() !== null) {
                    $($('.filename')).empty();
                }
                $('<span>' + file + '</span>').appendTo('.filename');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

my CSS :

```
#file_button {
   display: none;  
}
```

// then down goes the css for upload button

HTML :

```
<button type="button" class="upload"> Upload a File </button>
<p class="filename"> </p>
<input type="file" id="file_button"/>
```

Comment: Bind an `onchange` event to the input.

Comment: $('#file_button').click(); is doing nothing

Comment: How ..? sorry forgot to say i'm still new in jquery @Nilotpal Barpujari

Comment: `if(file !== null){  if($('.filename').val() !== null){ ` Looks like you really want to be sure. Guess what value will never be null. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hx2Hx/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".filename").each(function () {
        $('.upload').click(function () {
            $('#file_button').click();

        });

        $("#file_button").change(function () {
            var file = $('#file_button').val();
            if (file !== null) {
                if ($('.filename').val() !== null) {
                    $($('.filename')).empty();
                }
                $('<span>' + file + '</span>').appendTo('.filename');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#file_button").on('change',function(){
    alert('Selected');
});
```

Then do want you intended by replacing the alert.